# Why is the pod init command no found?

Tags: xcode, firebase

I'm trying to set up firebase for my Xcode app and when I type pod init into the terminal I get the error:

```
zsh: command not found: pod
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Did you install CocoaPods? https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#prerequisites In the prerequisite: Install CocoaPods...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install CocoaPods on your Mac.  You can find instructions on the [CocoaPods website](https://cocoapods.org/).